# How to access past events on Firebase analytics?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I'm trying to see the custom events parameters generated in my app but i can't seem to find the location to view past events (not only the last 30 min) this is what i'm seeing:

[image]

Any way i could access these past events with parameters?